# What is the warning triangle appearing at Lumia 435's screen top?

Tags: screen

Sometimes I see a warning-like triangle between the two cellular antennas at the top left corner of my Lumia 435 Dual SIM screen. What is it?
Sorry for the bad image I got using Cam.

[image]

Update:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see the image very well, but the only triangle that I know of means the phone is roaming. You could confirm this by going to Settings > Cellular + SIM and setting data roaming options to "don't roam", then check if the triangle is still there.

Comment: I checked the section you mentioned and roaming was off (don't roam). But, the triangle still persists without any further notification. It seems in certain places it appears, for example my cellular data connectivity is not available.

Comment: The "don't roam" option only applies to data transfer - the triangle itself is saying that you are connected to a network that does not belong to your provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn OFF your SIM 1 then it goes away, so perhaps it's just an indicator that your SIM is ON. Maybe, because it's not the one selected by default make calls, you get a triangle instead of the phone with the little arrow. I get that indicator but next to my 2nd SIM.

Comment: I don't think it is indicating that SIM is on, because it appears only in certain places. I @Shawn was right on this. And by the way, when I get this triangle I also have problem accessing cellular data using SIM 1.